# find resources that are never tagged in aws using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

Using this we can't find resources that are never tagged:

```
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
```

How to find resources that are **never tagged** in AWS using boto3?

Comment: AWS does not have a single API call for that. You need to develop custom solution.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a tagging concept that requires 5 tags as mandatory, and we created a config rule that checks for these.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/required-tags.html